# class and methods in python. introduction in oop

Tags: python, class, oop, object, methods

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        """Make a new person with the given name."""
        self.myname = name

    def introduction(myname):
        """Returns an introduction for this person."""
        return "Hi, my name is {}.".format(myname)

# Use the class to introduce Mark and Steve
mark = Person("Mark")
steve = Person("Steve")

print(mark.introduction())
print(steve.introduction())
```

its suppose to produce 
"Hi, my name is Mark." or "Hi, my name is Steve."

but instead it produces 
"Hi, my name is undefined."

Comment: Why must you hate indenting?

Comment: @mrdomoboto that really wasn't needed dude. Just ask the guy to indent his code.

Comment: im sorry. i dont understand. indenting which one?

Comment: @Mr.Python It's basic courtesy when you're asking others to help you out with a question in a language that relies on white-space for scope.

Comment: I completely agree. But there no need to say it that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be printing the object's representation in memory (something along the lines of `Hi, my name is <__main__.Person object at 0x005CEA10>`).

The reason is that the first argument of a method is expected to be the object that the method is called upon.

Just like you have `def __init__(self, name):` you should have `def introduction(self, myname):`.

Then you will encounter another problem, as `introduction` now expects an argument `myname` which you don't provide. However, it is not needed now since you have access to `self.myname`.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        """Make a new person with the given name."""
        self.myname = name

    def introduction(self):
        """Returns an introduction for this person."""
        return "Hi, my name is {}.".format(self.myname)


# Use the class to introduce Mark and Steve
mark = Person("Mark")
steve = Person("Steve")

print(mark.introduction())
print(steve.introduction())
```

Will output

```
Hi, my name is Mark.
Hi, my name is Steve.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `introduction()` -> `introduction(self)` as an instance method (*by passing in* `self`) to be able to access the instance variable `self.myname`.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        """Make a new person with the given name."""
        self.myname = name

    def introduction(self):
        """Returns an introduction for this person."""
        return "Hi, my name is {}.".format(self.myname)
```

**Sample output:**

```
# Use the class to introduce Mark and Steve
mark = Person("Mark")
steve = Person("Steve")

print(mark.introduction())
print(steve.introduction())
>>> Hi, my name is Mark.
>>> Hi, my name
```

Please note however, that the first parameter in a function within a **class** is reserved for either a class, or object to pass itself to (*unless a* [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) *tag is applied to the method, then the first implicit parameter is not passed; which essentially behave as module methods*).

Also keep in mind that `self` is not a reserved word, so you could name it anything (*even though* `self` *is PEP convention*). The below example executes the same output as the example above, and is *semantically* the same.

```
def introduction(myname):
    """Returns an introduction for this person."""
    return "Hi, my name is {}.".format(myname.myname)
```

[9.3.5. Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your giving your introduction method the parameter `myname`, but never supplying it with a  valid argument.You can simply do:

```
mark = Person(" Mark")
steve = Person(" Steve")

print(mark.introduction(mark.myname))
print(steve.introduction(steve.myname))
```

your giving the introduction method, the variable from your class `myname`.

But the above is not even necessary. Since your initializing your name variable in the `__init__` method of your class, it is like a global variable. So you can simply say:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        """Make a new person with the given name."""
        self.myname = name

    def introduction(self):
        """Returns an introduction for this person."""
        return "Hi, my name is{}".format(self.myname)


# Use the class to introduce Mark and Steve
mark = Person(" Mark")
steve = Person(" Steve")

print(mark.introduction())
print(steve.introduction())
```